# How do you you copy data from one field to another and append a text string in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

So I've got a pdf that is a form fillable student information card, my boss wants me to write javascript code that copies the whatever is typed in the username field into the email field and append the new text in the email field with @College.edu

So I've done bit of research and found a code snippet that gets the job half done with a function, but now I can't activate this function. All of my google searches either use jquery to get this done or html and I can't use either of those since I'm programming this in a pdf document

Here's the code I have so far:

```js
function copydata(){
var box1 = document.getElementById("Username");
var box2 = document.getElementById("Email");
box1.value = box2.value;
}
```

I tried everything I can think of to get this function to execute with like an onblur or onfocus method, I would be fine with it if it copied over as the person was typing into the first field. Nothing I do works however and the debugger console literally tells me nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

[Form Fallible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Vxx.png)
[Debugger Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHYbd.png)

Comment: do you want to copy whatever he types in the e-mail field while he's typing or after he finishes typing ?

Comment: I want to copy anything typed in the username field to the email field with @College.edu appended in that field. Because the the end-users username is exactly the same as their email address, doing this avoid redundant typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean that?

```js
function handleChange(e) {
  document.getElementById("Email").value = e.target.value + "@College.edu";
}

Username.addEventListener("keyup", handleChange, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Username" />
<input type="email" id="Email" />
```

Comment: Well close but i don't think the pdf form fillable document will handle html. I tried the above method although your function is way different.

Comment: HTML tags - only for example. ;) You can use this code as you need.

Comment: it's giving me a reference error for the last line where the event listener is, says Username is not defined, which is weird because when I click on the username field what is indeed what its named.

Comment: You can try to add an attribute `onkeyup="handleChange(event)"`.

Comment: I'll try that in a bit and let you know how it goes. Thank you again for your help, I do appreciate it. :)

Comment: Have a nice day!

Comment: Still not working, i added the line document.onkeyup="handlechange(event)" and it's still not copying over my input from username to email.

Comment: So apparently I was supposed to be doing this in the actions section of the field properties

Comment: In the action section for each field, there is an onfocus action I can program a function in. Question is can I call variables in between fields because I will need to capture input from the username field and write it out in the Email field.

Comment: I think i found an answer. You need to use `getField("text2").value = getField("text1").valueAsString;` (where "text2" and "text1" - your fields) in your onfocus or onblur events.

Comment: I could literally kiss you right now. it worked. And I appended get("text1").valueAsString + "@Brazosport.edu".

Comment: Thank you so much!